groovy DatabaseUtil.withSql not connecting
I must state upfront that I'm a seasoned C#/Java developer but I have very little Oracle or Jira ScriptRunner experience.
The company I work for is running Jira v9.15.2 and I'm trying to execute an Oracle stored proc that updates some tables in Jenkins ScriptRunner, when a specific event is triggered.  The stored proc has 4 parameters, of which the first 2 are optional and the 3rd is an out parameter.
I've written a script in IntelliJ that does what it needs to do (inserting a record):
    {  
   
        def sql = Sql.newInstance('my jdbc url', 'my username', 'my password',    'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver')  
        sql.call("{CALL 'my schema.my package.my stored proc(?, ?, ?, ?)}'",
                [entity_no, null, Sql.VARCHAR, detected_by], { result ->
            String outString = result.toString()  
            if (outString.startsWith('Process Successful'))  
            {  
                //Some logic here  
            }  
        })  
        sql.close()  
    }  

However, when I try to run it in ScriptRunner it complains that it cannot find 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'. In any case, from the Jira documentation it seems that it is not recommended to do it this way.
So I created a Database connection in Resources:
Pool name: oracle
JDBC URL: 'my jdbc url'
Driver class name: 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' (from the "Show examples")
The connection work fine when I test it in the input box provided
My Jira script looks like this:
    {  
        DatabaseUtil.withSql('oracle') {sql ->  
                sql.call("{CALL 'my schema.my package.my stored proc(?, ?, ?, ?)}'",
                [entity_no, null, Sql.VARCHAR, detected_by] , { result ->  
                    String outString = result.toString()  
                    if (outString.startsWith('Process Successful'))  
                    {  
                        //Some logic here  
                    } 
            }  
            })  
            sql.close()  
    }  

The IntelliJ version returns 'Process Successful...' in 'result', while the Jira version returns " General Error: ORA-01403: no data found"
I have tried changing 'Sql.VARCHAR' to other types, as well as 'Sql.out(Sql.VARCHAR.getType())' and all iterations I can think of.
When I replace the stored proc with a select statement it returns the correct results for the select statement. We are not allowed to update tables except through stored procs.
When I give both optional parameters a value, the IntelliJ version returns a message that it is not allowed (as expected) but the Jira version still returns the ORA-01403.
Out of desperation I changed he name of the proc to something invalid, and it brought back the same. So I know I'm missing something fundamental but doesn't know what it is.

it's not clear what is your question. ORA-01403: no data found - is quite standard issue in oracle, that you have to debug in your database and it's not related to groovy. my guess is wrong sproc parameter value.

Could it be that you have a misplaced quote?  The trailing single quote occurs after the } which isn't going to work.  Try moving it to surround the method name like so:
sql.call("{CALL 'my schema.my package.my stored proc'(?, ?, ?, ?)}", [entity_no, null, Sql.VARCHAR, detected_by]) { result ->
}

You are also passing the closure as a parameter in the method.  You can just use the typical groovy syntax with the closure passed after the closing param ) of the method call.  That might make things a little more readable and predictable for Groovy.  I've done that above in the example I provided.
The 'my schema.my package.my stored proc' line seems like it's extra complicated.  Maybe you could just rename the stored procedure to something simpler like this and nix the quote single quote syntax:
sql.call("{CALL doJiraInsert( ?, ? , ? , ? )}", [entity_no, null, Sql.VARCHAR, detected_by]) { result ->
 ....
}

If the out parameter is giving you headaches you could simply return whatever you were trying to do like this:
sql.call("{? = call doJiraInserts( ?, ?, ? )}", [Sql.VARCHAR, entity_no, detected_by, null]) { result ->
   ...
}

And finally if the null is giving you headaches you could try just using default values in the stored proc and not pass it like so:
sql.call("{CALL doJiraInserts(?, ?, ?)}", [entity_no, Sql.VARCHAR, detected_by]) { result ->
}

But, I suspect you will need to wrap that null in an InParameter.  A raw null isn't going to work because of types needed by SQL stored procs.
sql.call("{CALL doJiraInsert( ?, ? , ? , ? )}", [entity_no, Sql.NULL(null), Sql.VARCHAR, detected_by]) { result ->
 ....
}

Nulls and JDBC are not friends because JDBC needs to know a field's type beforehand.  When you pass a valid reference to a non-null you can interrogate its class.  But if you pass a null for a String/Integer/Boolean.  JDBC can't figure out the type of it and it doesn't like it.  I think JDBC could be "smarter", but unfortunately this has been a design flaw since the beginning on it.  Wrapping it in an InParameter that know it's a null probably will fix it.

In the end I realize that the ScriptRunner Oracle driver was set up as read-only.  Thanks for commenting
